# How can I understand the encryption method for this code?

Tags: bash, shell, encryption, decode, encode

Someone is asking my client to execute a script on their server. Although the person is trusted but they are trying to hide what the script is actually doing. This might be a Python, Bash or Ruby script. Here are the first few lines:

```sh
ELF����������>����¯&@�����@�������������������@�8��@���������������������@�������@�����‚.������‚.�������� �����������0������0å`�����0å`����������������������������QÂtd��������������������������������������������������ò¶l?���!Ù
����Pë��Pë��8��¿������˚˚!ˇELF��>�
@@ªdø�êâ"8�›≤Óª ��'@‰Ñ<!¯��‰{õÓ8
@ôê'��|`{oçLO�~…∂Ñ� 7´]œN»˜
`†7@.wr!^$ÉM»`ﬂ§õ2T@ôê'D��PÂÚΩﬂtd¨E
@‰gK»�7Qßg∞#∞�oRf  ø��ÄÑá@��ˇM��w��I�€ª˝/lib64d-nux-x86-.˜¶€˛so.2���GNU��öœ4› ˜ˇˇAÙ6«[9ÅGüa¢ÂH#∞   ÔÌ/ÿ8C7à¡ 
@ˇˇo∫:=BE’Ïª„í|∏çÒ8ÚãŸqX∞n ˚Î”Ô��™PÑ] ≈�˙/!Ï9ne_¬Üê›uGçê!lÛ¬ÜÃèñÜ∞!l//fßÏd¬èΩõ¬Üê!F∞/rl_
!C»±£»6ÑwD_ÜB.êCÅS!l!/\ á∞/ïîß2Ñào6Ñ`G(K_aC»m/6Ñ
YwY_
........................
```

How can I determine the encryption method for this file? I want to decode it before advising the client to execute it even if the provider is trusted one. The client wants to know exactly what does this script do. Without knowing the encryption method, we can't decode it and the provider is reluctant to share the encryption method.

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes, I don't know what the programming language is used for this script. It is used to activate the license from the provider but this sounds strange. I just want to know the encoding method here.

Comment: Why do you believe this is encrypted (it doesn't particularly look encrypted). Why do you believe it's written in a scripting language, rather than C++ for example. This is reasonable output for any compiled language. (It could also be a script, wrapped up in a compiled language. It could be anything, and it could do just about anything.)

Comment: @RobNapier Please pardon me in that case. I only know bash, PHP, Python and JavaScript. In PHP, I have found encrypted code to be like this. That's why I posted this question. I have no idea on a compiled language.

Comment: This definitely isn't encrypted in any case (if it were, you'd need to provide it a decryption key to run it). At best it's obfuscated (i.e. the decryption logic is inside the executable). Reverse-engineering an obfuscation scheme is beyond the scope of StackOverflow (and impossible given the output you've provided). I would budget between several hundred and several thousand dollars to hire someone to de-obfuscate this. (I wouldn't particularly advise that; I'd advise resolving this between the parties through negotiation.)

Comment: The first 3 characters are `ELF`. That's the standard format for binary executable programs on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an ELF format executable.  The "ELF" characters are the giveaway.

There is no obvious sign that it is encrypted.   Indeed, I can see sequences of characters that make some sense as text.  (Those will be strings embedded in the executable.)

An ELF executable cannot be fully encrypted.  If encryption *has been* used, then the executable will include the (machine) instructions that tell your computer how to decrypt.

> The client wants to know exactly what does this script do.

I would start by using the (Linux) `file` command to confirm the file type, then look for a tool that will allow you to disassemble or decompile the executable.

> I only know bash, PHP, Python and JavaScript.

Then you probably don't have the skills to answer your client's question.  This will require skills in assembly language (probably for Intel x86 or x86-64) and possibly C or C++ if you can find a decompiler that works for this code.